# dictionary-base text analysis with approximate matching

Tags: search, lucene, named-entity-recognition, text-analysis, named-entity-extraction

I have a database/dictionary of over 2 million names, phases , locations and so on. A sample data is the following:

```
“A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new”

“Nelson Mandela”

“United States of America”

“I didn't attend the funeral, but I sent a nice letter saying I approved of it.”

“Joseph Campbell”

“Insanity: doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results”

“United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland”
```

For each entry, there is an ID.

Now, when a user submit a text to my website, the text will be analyzed and will find all the appearances of names, phases and locations in the text with some forgiveness (approximate matching). For examples:

1. The phase “Insanity: doing the same thing over and over again” will be matched with the complete phase “Insanity: doing the same thing over and over again **and expecting different results**”
2. The phase “Insanity: doing the same thing over again and expecting different results” will be matched with the complete phase “Insanity: doing the same thing over **and over** again and expecting different results”

I don’t know if this is a Named Entity problem as my database has phases that are more than 2 lines long. I also don’t want to find the exact phase, I want to approximate matching.

I am looking for open source solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to look at a search engine like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). It basically creates its own database where you put your documents - in your case "Insanity: doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results". Then you can do a search with "Insanity, over and over" and the engine will give you an ordered list of results. It's highly configurable.

Depending on your task you could probably implement your own [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) with the possible phrases you need to match. Or you could implement an enhanced [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) giving better scores for specific phrases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of Lucene, and if you noticed I have it as a keyword in my question. Lucene alone doesn't solve my problem. However, luckly, as of v8.2, lucence can do 'reverse search' .

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old questions, but I found a solution for this problem and I want to share it with you all.

https://github.com/flaxsearch/luwak which is now part of Lucene as of the version 8.2 is a "a high performance stored query engine. Simply put, it allows you to define a set of search queries and then monitor a stream of documents for any that might match these queries: a function also known as 'reverse search' and 'document routing'. "